# Is there a way to put a pseudo element behind the text node?

Tags: html, css

I have an element that has a `::before` pseudo element as background.

But as you can see the pseudo element is covering my text.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: salmon;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tag {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tag::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(1.2) translateY(50%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(closest-side, steelblue 99%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="tag">Lorum ipsum</span>
</div>
```

I wish I can target the text node by

```css
.tag:text {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

But it's not possible.

I tried to give the pseudo element `z-index: -1;` but it's covered by anything that has a background such as `.wrapper`, since all their backgrounds has default `z-index` of `0`.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: salmon;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tag {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tag::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(1.2) translateY(50%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(closest-side, steelblue 99%, transparent 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="tag">Lorum ipsum</span>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve:

[image]

How can I achieve it without modifying the html structure?

Comment: Have you tried using `:after` instead of `:before`?

Comment: @HansSpieß Yes and it's the same outcome :(

Comment: the default value is not 0 but auto. make the pseudo element -1 and the tag 0, it will work

Answer (score 2):

Add `z-index` on `.tag`

```
.tag {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: salmon;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tag {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tag::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(1.2) translateY(50%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(closest-side, steelblue 99%, transparent 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="tag">Lorum ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wait, does that mean whatever `z-index` the child has, as long as their parent has a bigger `z-index`, it's allways gonna be displayed on the top? Even with a negative `z-index`?

Comment: @HaoWu not bigger, as long as the parent has any value of z-index (other than auto). Read the duplicate for more detail

Answer (score 0):

Positive `z-index` on `.tag` and negative on `.tag::before`

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: salmon;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tag {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tag::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(1.2) translateY(50%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(closest-side, steelblue 99%, transparent 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="tag">Lorum ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Comment: isn't this exactly copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/67264333/10698741 ?

Comment: @doğukan Yeah, appears so. I didn't see his code snippet as I was testing mine in JSFiddle. Anyway, your solution is quite interesting, I didn't think of the negative `translateZ`. Congrats on the pick, well deserved!